# Android studio web socket - Error receiving multiple JSON objects at once

Tags: android, json, websocket

I am struggling with something that really p*sses me off for several hours.

My android app manages to connect to a websoket, and receives json data which for now has worked perfectly, and here is the code for this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSocket.on("dev0", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    try {



                        JSONObject incomingPositionFromSensor = new JSONObject( (String) args[0]);
                        double the_position = incomingPositionFromSensor.getDouble("position");
                        CalculateValue(the_position);



                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                }
            });

        }

    });

}
```

This code above as I said works perfectly, and i get the data in everytime. HOWEVER, HOWEVER, HOWEVER: If i try to receive 2 json-objects at the sametime through this emittener, it does not work!!!!

Here is example when i try to receive multiple JSON objects, and NONE of them works!

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                mSocket.on("dev0", new Emitter.Listener() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(Object... args) {
                        try {


                            JSONObject incomingTargetFromSensor = new JSONObject( (String) args[0]);
                            int targetNum = incomingTargetFromSensor.getInt("target_number_count");
                            showTargetRep(targetNum); //NOT WORKING!

                            JSONObject incomingPositionFromSensor = new JSONObject( (String) args[0]);
                            double the_position = incomingPositionFromSensor.getDouble("position");
                            CalculateValue(the_position); //NOT WORKING!




                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                    }
                });

            }

        });

    }
```

In the first example I could receive the position data, and the code is exactly similar as the example above, but for some reasons it can not recevice data when i try to receive another JSON object.

Another example of why I always disliked JSON object.

Any help plz?

Answer (score 0):

The solution at the end was to add multiple try/catches like this:

```
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            mSocket.on("dev0", new Emitter.Listener() {

                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {

                    try {


                        JSONObject incomingTargetRepFromSensor = new JSONObject((String ) args[0]);
                        int target_rep = incomingTargetRepFromSensor.getInt("target_repetition_count");
                        showTargetRep(target_rep);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        JSONObject incomingDataFromSensor = new JSONObject((String ) args[0]);
                        double the_position = incomingDataFromSensor.getDouble("position");
                        CalculateValue(the_position);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        JSONObject incomingTargetSetFromSensor = new JSONObject((String ) args[0]);
                        int target_set = incomingTargetSetFromSensor.getInt("target_set_count");
                        showTargetSet(target_set);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try{
                        JSONObject incomingRepsFromSensor = new JSONObject((String ) args[0]);
                        int the_repetitions = incomingRepsFromSensor.getInt("repetitions");
                        showCurrentReps(the_repetitions);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try{
                        JSONObject incomingSetsFromSensor = new JSONObject((String ) args[0]);
                        int the_sets = incomingSetsFromSensor.getInt("sets");
                        showCurrentSets(the_sets);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });

}
```